# Stuck at Creating Keys for Token - cardano-cli address key-gen

Tags: nft, cardano-cli, minting

I feel like an idiot but I am stuck at creating the keys for a token.

Here is the code:

> cardano@transmission:/home/transmission/Documents$ sudo mkdir policy && cd policy

> cardano@transmission:/home/transmission/Documents/policy$ cardano-cli address key-gen 
> --verification-key-file policy.vkey 
> --signing-key-file policy.skey

> Command failed: address key-gen  Error: policy.skey: policy.skey: openBinaryFile: permission denied (Permission denied)

Do you have any idea why I am being denied permission for this command?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Ok I am an idiot for asking and answering this,but I am doing it anyways in case somebody stumbles in the same problem.

The folder for the keys needs to be created in the the directory where the node is in. In my case Cardano.

Comment: Your "policy" directory is owned by the root user, since you used `sudo mkdir policy`. No need to use sudo to make directories in your home folder, you can either remove and re-create "policy" without sudo, or change the owner with `sudo chown -R <username> <directory>`